# Convince Product Managers to Change Design of a Long Running Synchronous Process

Tags: java, web-applications, java-ee-5

In our web application, we have a feature which:

1. Gets a list of products
2. Writes them to an excel file
3. Returns the excel file to the user for download

This process takes more often depending on the number of products > 2 minutes. Some requests take more than 5 minutes! On average users download 100-500 products and the request takes somewhere around 1 - 5 minutes.

I think 1 minute is too long for any web server thread to be active on any single request. Aside from the fact that it takes so long, the process itself causes out of memory errors in our server and makes it crash.

I would like to convince them that this is bad practice and hence the design must be changed by citing articles or books or studies written by software architects saying that this is so along with recommendations on what to do in this situation.

Anyone know such books/articles/studies?

If you disagree with me in the assumption that 1 minute is too long for any web server thread to be active on a single request, kindly let me know why.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried rethinking the logic to generate the xls? Because if it is a business requirement then they might be really reluctant to change(been there, done that) it.

I have used apache-poi to generate xls and create reports and for the performance satisfactory(max few secs to make the report). We used server side caching to cache the data. and then we would just pull out the xls.

Comment: +1. Can you point me to leads on how to cache the data? We're using POI in this feature and even then, the process still takes a long time.

Comment: Not sure what your architecture is but caching can be as simple as using ehcache with hibernate to using  OSCache(http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/) to cache complex objects using. Also Timer tasks can be used to periodically extract data and cache it(in OSCache). So your excel generation logic has to do minimum amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of Excels being downloaded is fixed, you can think of generating them in background thread and return a direct link for download. Even if it changes once in an hour or 2 its worth doing that instead of generating on demand.

The other approach could be, when users select the product list and request the Excel provide an option if they would like to receive an email with the download link or even receive the file as attachment to the email. If they accept, submit each request to a Queue and run a batch job that generates the Excel sheet and sends them as mail attachment. This way you would not throttle the web server.

In addition, my main question would be why is it taking more than a minute, which part of the process is taking long time. Its worth investigating that area (DB connectivity {pooling, co-locate the servers}, huge table {partition}, excel generation)?

Are you adding fixed graphics to each excel? if so use templates that already have the headers/footers etc.

Its worth re-looking at the pieces that are creating bottlenecks rather than blindly saying its a bad design/approach.

Investigation would probably fix the current issues or at least you would not carry forward the same mistakes in future design